# Adding env to options when doing L.tileLayer.wms for leaflet

Tags: angular, leaflet, geoserver, wms, ngx-leaflet

I have an application using [ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/), Leaflet for Angular, and I'm trying to do a `L.titleLayer.wms` but adding an extra option to `tileLayer.wms`. It looks likes this:

```
L.tileLayer.wms(url, {
    layers: layerName,
    format: 'image/png8',
    version: '1.1.0',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: "",
    tileSize: 512,
    styles: styleName,
    env: env // This is the additional option that I am trying to add
});
```

However, when I try to do this, I get the following error: `Argument of type '{ layers: string; format: string; version: string; transparent: true; attribution: string; tileSize: number; styles: string; env: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WMSOptions'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'env' does not exist in type 'WMSOptions'`

I'm pretty sure it's because the library only accepts these options for `WMSOptions`:

```
export interface WMSOptions extends TileLayerOptions {
    layers?: string | undefined;
    styles?: string | undefined;
    format?: string | undefined;
    transparent?: boolean | undefined;
    version?: string | undefined;
    crs?: CRS | undefined;
    uppercase?: boolean | undefined;
}
```

So I tried to extend `TileLayer` and created another file that looks like this:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';

export namespace ExtendWMS {
    export class WMS extends L.TileLayer {
        constructor(baseUrl: string, options: ExtendOptions) {            
            super (baseUrl, options)
        };

        setParams(params: ExtendParams, noRedraw?: boolean): this {
            return this;
        }

        wmsParams: ExtendParams;
        options: ExtendOptions;
    }
}

export namespace extendLayer {
    function wms(baseUrl: string, options: ExtendOptions): L.TileLayer.WMS {
        return new ExtendWMS.WMS(baseUrl, options)
    };
}

export interface ExtendOptions extends L.WMSOptions{
    env?: string | undefined;
}


export interface ExtendParams extends L.WMSParams{
    env?: string | undefined;
}
```

This is so that the `WMSOptions` will have the `env` variable that I need to add to the call, but when I do this and call it,

```
ExtendWMS.WMS(url, {
    layers: layerName,
    format: 'image/png8',
    version: '1.1.0',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: "",
    tileSize: 512,
    styles: styleName,
    env: env // This is the additional option that I am trying to add
});
```

I am unable to add the layer to the map and I notice that the `wmsParams` is missing: `t.WMS {_url: url, options: {…}, _events: {…}, _initHooksCalled: true}` when I try to console log the `L.tileLayer.wms` call...(I noticed that `url`, `options` and `wmsParams` is all present in the `L.tileLayer.wms` call)

Is there a way I can include the `env` option to `WMSOption` so that when I do a `L.tileLayer.wms` call, it will accept the env as a parameter? I'm trying to do this because I want to change the style for the specific layer in GeoServer: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#env

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do to get it to work is:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';

export class ExtendWMS extends L.TileLayer {
    constructor(baseUrl: string, options: ExtendOptions ) {
        super (baseUrl, options)

        L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
    };
}

export interface ExtendOptions extends L.WMSOptions {
    layers: string ;
    styles?: string | undefined;
    format?: string | undefined;
    transparent?: boolean | undefined;
    version: string;
    crs?: L.CRS | undefined;
    uppercase?: boolean | undefined;
    env?: string | undefined;
    attribution?: string|undefined,
    tileSize?: number|undefined,
    icon: string|undefined,
    tiled: boolean|undefined,
}
```

Comment: Great! It does the trick! Thank you for sharing ;)